# I need to convert the series into a dataframe so that I can give the columns the names I want

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with information about movies. I'm interested in the columns "Production Company" and "Award". I had to group the dataframe by companies and calculate the number of awards received for them, and then display the three companies with the most value. I did this and got a series:

```
mv['Award'] = mv['Award'].astype('string')
mv['Winners'] = mv['Award'] == 'Winner'
mv['Winners']=mv['Winners'].astype('string')
mv['Winners'] = mv['Winners'].str.replace('False','')
mv['Winners'] = mv['Winners'].notnull()
mv['Winners']=mv['Winners'].astype('string')
mv['Winners']=mv['Winners'].str.replace('True','Oscar')
Number_Award = mv.groupby(['Production Company'])['Winners'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(3)
print(Number_Award)

**Result:**
Production Company      Winners
Paramount Pictures      Oscar      33
Warner Bros. Pictures   Oscar      29
MGM Home Entertainment  Oscar      28
Name: Winners, dtype: int64
```

Then I tried to convert to a dataframe and assign names to the columns, but I could not do this, since there was only one column with the name "Winners".
It looked like this:

```
Number_Award = Number_Award.to_frame()
Number_Award

**Result:**
Winners
Production Company  Winners 
Paramount Pictures  Oscar   33
Warner Bros. Pictures   Oscar   29
MGM Home Entertainment  Oscar   28
```

How do I remake the dataframe so it looks something like this:

```
Production Company  Award   Number of award
Paramount Pictures  Oscar   33
Warner Bros. Pictures   Oscar   29
MGM Home Entertainment  Oscar   28
```

Comment: Hi! Mind providing a sample input data fame and expected output ? (i.e. a [mcve]) - I can already tell you are doing a bunch of redundant operations that we can avoid and make it easier and faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column name in `Series.to_frame` then reset the index and rename the column

```py
out = (Number_Award.to_frame('Number of award')
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'Winners': 'Award'}))
```

```
print(out)

       Production Company  Award  Number of award
0  MGM Home Entertainment  Oscar                1
1      Paramount Pictures  Oscar                1
2   Warner Bros. Pictures  Oscar                1
```